The first line of a provisional application

In the provisional application drafted by an attorney, the first line looks like this.
Question:

Is this line needed?
Should the specifications document be in PDF or docx?
Should the drawings document be in PDF or docx?
Should the cover letter be in PDF or docx?


I don’t see the first quoted line.

I uploaded an image.

I see an image with just the top 1/2” of a page.

right, that's the first line that I was talking about. Right beneath that line is the title. So my question is, is that first line needed?

It’s not a first line. It’s a header. It consists of an attorney docket number and the word provisional.
This is not part of the content of the document.  Attorney docket number is meaningless to the USPTO.
No header format or even a header at all is required in provisional or non-provisional applications. You might look at a book like Patent it Yourself.
The “Provisional” at the top of the first page, or every page, could help keep the document from being understood to be a non-provisional due some other error.

Actually, it's not the docket number to the left. The crossed out info is a name for my application for the attorney to keep track of internally. This header is only on the first page.

But can you answer whether or not this header is needed? Or can it be removed? Should it be removed?

The designator for an application the attorney uses for internal purposes is called a docket number.
